# Tracking user views shopify

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify

I need to know if there is a way to track user views for products, products in the shopping cart that haven't been checked-out yet using rails shopify api or not.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Insert tracking code Javascript using a ScriptTag in your App. You can then create an App Proxy in your App to receive the JS calls. Count and do what you wish. The App Proxy is secure too. And as a bonus you can send the cart cookie ID to your App so that you can tell what was converted.